# Composable not recomposing when list is cleared in jetpack compose

Tags: android, list, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I have one `MutableStateFlow` which is kind of `emptyList`. When I add the item my view is recomposed without any problem. Now I want to recompose view when list is clear. I tried some piece of code but nothing happens.

**PairViewModel**

```
class PairViewModel : BaseViewModel() {
     val scanLowEnergyDevices by lazy { MutableStateFlow(emptyList<ScanResult>()) }

     fun addDevices(result: ScanResult) {
        scanLowEnergyDevices.value += result
    }
}
```

**ContentStateful**

```
@Composable
fun ContentStateful(
    context: Context = LocalContext.current,
    viewModel: BloodPressurePairViewModel = getViewModel()
) {
    val activity = context as ComponentActivity
    val scanDeviceList by viewModel.scanLowEnergyDevices.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
  
    ContentStateLess(
        scanDeviceList = scanDeviceList,
        resetAction = {
            viewModel.scanLowEnergyDevices.value.toMutableList().clear()
        }   
    )
}
```

**ContentStateLess**

```
@Composable
fun ContentStateLess(
    scanDeviceList: List<ScanResult>,
    resetAction: () -> Unit,
) {
    AnimatedVisibility(visible = scanDeviceList.isNotEmpty()) {
        Text(text = "scanDeviceList ${scanDeviceList.size}")
        Button(onClick = { resetAction() }) {
            Text(text = "Reset")
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong in here? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `SnapshotStateList` like this

```
val scanLowEnergyDevices by lazy { mutableStateListOf<ScanResult>() }
```

add items like this

```
fun addDevices(result: ScanResult) {
    scanLowEnergyDevices.add(result)
    // scanLowEnergyDevices.value.add(result)
}
```

and clear the list like you would do with a standard collection like this

```
resetAction = {
    viewModel.scanLowEnergyDevices.clear()
    // viewModel.scanLowEnergyDevices.value.clear()
}
```

or in your use-case, since its wrap inside a State, just call the `.value` before the `.add()` and `.clear()` calls

Comment: I used your code which is uncomment and it works fine for me. I didn't understand `since its wrap inside a State...` why should I need to use `.value` if I used your uncomment code? Thanks

Comment: Ohhh, because your posted code has a MutableState wrapping the list, I'm referring to the `MutableState` when I said `State`.

Comment: ok no problem. I used like you did in your code.. Thanks