# How to use mutableSetOf in SnapshotStateList in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, set, android-jetpack-compose

I want to make a list of unique items in my list in jetpack compose. So I am trying to use [MutableSet](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-set/#kotlin.collections.MutableSet) in my project. I know that [mutableStateListOf](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#mutableStateListOf()) is using for list in jetpack compose. I have another reason to use of [mutableStateListOf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74570692/8266651) in my project. So is there is way we can use of **`MutableSet`** with **`mutableStateListOf`** ?

```
 val list by lazy { mutableStateListOf<ScanResult>() }
```

Many Thanks